# Activating a Device with IAudioPeakMeter interface fails with E_NOINTERFACE in windows

Tags: windows, winapi, wasapi

My intention is to capture the audio level of microphones in windows system.

I am trying the following code and Activation of IPart to get IAudioPeakMeter fails with E_NOINTERFACE.

Any solutions to the following error or any other approaches to capture the audio level of microphones in windows system is highly appreciable?

```
HRESULT hr;
IMMDeviceEnumerator* pEnumerator = NULL;
IMMDevice* pDevice = NULL;
static float peak = 0;

CoInitialize(NULL);

// Get enumerator for audio endpoint devices.
hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator),
    NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
    __uuidof(IMMDeviceEnumerator),
    (void**)&pEnumerator);
DisplayMessageOnError(L"CoCreateInstance", hr);

hr = pEnumerator->GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(eCapture, eCommunications, &pDevice);
DisplayMessageOnError(L"GetDefaultAudioEndpoint", hr);

CComPtr<IDeviceTopology> topology;
hr = pDevice->Activate(__uuidof(IDeviceTopology), CLSCTX_ALL, NULL, (void**)&topology);
DisplayMessageOnError(L"Activate", hr);

CComPtr<IConnector> connector;
hr = topology->GetConnector(0, &connector);
DisplayMessageOnError(L"GetConnector", hr);

CComPtr<IConnector> connectedTo;
hr = connector->GetConnectedTo(&connectedTo);
DisplayMessageOnError(L"GetConnectedTo", hr);

//CComPtr<IPart> part;
//hr = connectedTo->QueryInterface(&part);
CComPtr<IPart> part = NULL;
hr = connectedTo->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IPart), (void**)&part);
DisplayMessageOnError(L"QueryInterface", hr);

CComPtr<IAudioPeakMeter> audio;
**//Below code fails with E_NOINTERFACE.**
hr = part->Activate(CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, __uuidof(IAudioPeakMeter), (void**)&audio);
DisplayMessageOnError(L"part->Activate", hr);

audio->GetLevel(0,&peak);
std::wstringstream wstr;
wstr << L"GetPeakValue " << peak << '\n';
OutputDebugStringW(wstr.str().c_str());

return S_OK;
```

Comment: It just means your hardware setup and drivers don't support this interface which is optional. From documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/devicetopology/nn-devicetopology-iaudiopeakmeter *The call to IPart::Activate succeeds only if the subunit supports the IAudioPeakMeter interface. Only a subunit object that represents a hardware peak meter will support this interface* PS: you should use CLSCTX_ALL instead of CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER (that won't probably change the result here)

Comment: E_NOINTERFACE means the object pointed to by pConnectTo is not a valid connector object. Check this link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/azure/en-us/f7fa662b-df73-44ec-b84f-df77f31a525d/2085120110com3245220214queryinterface3682022238enointerface30340383823906